# Find apostrophe symbol ' in PDF file

Tags: font-encodings, copy-paste, apostrophe

I'm writing in french, with AZERTY keyboard and I don't know why I not can find the apostrophe symbol ' in my PDF file ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel}

\begin{document}
\noindent
d'utile\\
l'importance\\
qu'il\\
s'efface
\end{document}
```

display

[image: apostrophe]

but when I try to find in my PDF file (CTRL+F) any word with apostrophe symbole (like: "d'utile", "l'importance",...), the search engine does not find the apostrophe.

Comment: I've got no problem with SumatraPDF, not Adobe Reader.

Comment: This is probably due to the fact you don't type the typographical apostrophe (« guillemet-apostrophe » U+2019), obtainable on an Azerty keyboard as `Alt+0146`. I guess you type U+0027, which you obtain under the `4` in the first row of the keyboard.

Comment: @Bernard I can find "d'ut" without problems. But it could depend on the (unknown)  pdf viewer and the (unknown) version of the fonts.

Comment: I'm using EVINCE for the pdf viewer in Linux.
@Bernard, it is right, I type in my pdf search engine the straight dactylographical apostrophe (from the `4` touch of AZERTY keyboard, I'm doing this, because on my latex source file, I also type this same straight dactylographical apostrophe.